# How to determine encoding?

Tags: outlook, decode, encode, python-unicode, eml

## Problem

I have an e-mail that I have problems reading into Python with the correct encoding though Outlook can read it correctly.

## Reading a message

```
import email
message = email.message_from_file(open('/path/to/file.eml'))
```

## Example

This is part of an email which should be decoded to "Denne her får du":

```
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Denne=20her=20f=EF=BF=BDr=20du
```

When I decode it with UTF-8, I get the following:

```
import quopri
mystring = 'Denne=20her=20f=EF=BF=BDr=20du'
decoded_string = quopri.decodestring(mystring)
print(decoded_string.decode('utf-8'))
>Denne her f�r du
```

When I just open the e-mail in Outlook I get:

"Denne her får du"

## How do I decode it correctly?

Is there somewhere else in the e-mail, what I can see the correct encoding? There must be right? Else how is Outlook able to decode the message?

Comment: The fact that you are getting only 1 `�` where the `å` character is expected means the data is being *decoded* properly, it is just not being *displayed* properly, ie if your console window is using a font that doesn't support the `å` character.

Comment: What code do you use for reading message bodies?